# iPad Safari iOS - SECURITY_ERR: Dom Exception 18 when accessing "document.cookie"

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, domexception

Running Safari on iOS 5.1 (iPad), my JavaScript code is throwing the following exception:

> SECURITY_ERR: Dom Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through
>   the security policy of the user agent

...whenever I make a call to `document.cookie`

Now this is a remotely hosted website accessed via a proper URL. All desktop browsers run fine, this only affects Safari on my iPad. I tried to Google the error, but I'm just getting references to calling local files (file://) which I'm not doing as it's a remote website.

Any ideas?

Comment: There were changes made in 5.1 that altered how\where things like cookies, LocalStorage and WebDB's are stored. I get the same error when working with localStorage and WebDBs in a Mobile project. I see output in xCode that shows 2 different AppIDs when I work with localStorage and I think this might be similiar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: OK, this is weird. I force quite Safari on the iPad (double tap home button, then hold down Safari icon), then re-opened Safari, and no errors. Works fine now, typical! #sigh

Comment: Yeah, I had weirdness too where my "older" application worked fine in 5.1 UNTIL I deleted the app and re-installed. From that point forward, the app was toast and wouldn't do anything.

Comment: I second what Sunday Ironfoot is saying, except I'm hitting the issue via PhoneGap calling window.openDatabase().  If I force-close the app and run again, however, it works fine and the database does work.  (Either that or I still have a DB installed before the 5.1 changes and am falling back onto it.)

Comment: I had this exact issue with the same resolution. Nearly gave me a heart attack as I tried debugging going into production.

Comment: Do you have any HTTP dumps?  It might be that your cookie is pushed with the httpOnly flag.

Comment: +1 Voting to reopen as I think finding an answer to this question will help future visitors as the question may not be as localised as it first appears. The second comment by @SundayIronfoot is a good work around but not a permanent solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue running my web application in a LG Smart TV. `navigator.cookieEnabled` returns true but `document.cookie` throws DOM exception 18.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable cookie? May be cookies are blocked.
2. Protocol missmatch? Http script in https page, for example.
3. To big cookie size?
4. Illegal character in cookie value?
5. Are you using iOS UIWebView? It's can be a not uri scheme protocol (aka file://)
6. Are you trying to get cookie from iframe?

Check all of this, sometimes it's strange like a magic.